# How to avoid the id getting displayed in the address bar when a user click that link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an anchor tag inside a `<li>` tag like this

```
<li><a href="#fragment-1">Primary Details</a></li>
```

But the problem is that I want the link to show the div with id fragment-1. but after the link is clicked, the div id is being displayed in the url like below

```
http://localhost:90/index.php#fragment-1
```

How can i stop the div id being displayed with the url ??

Comment: That's how anchor tags work.  You could use some javascript to go to the element that you want instead.

Comment: I would add that it's usually a bad idea to use JS to mimic this functionality without the # in the address bar because that removes the browser's ability to use the back/forward buttons for navigation between the visited named anchors on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, naturally anyways.  You can try some clever JavaScript to mimic this behavior and leave the URL unscathed.

- http://clifgriffin.com/2008/10/14/using-javascript-to-scroll-to-a-specific-elementobject/

Personally, I like the #hashtags in the URLs. Sometime I want to share a link and point the reader to a specific part of the page.

Comment: But will this work in form wizard where i have next and back button?

Comment: Ah... and the plot thickens.  @Bala.C, remember that we can't actually see your screen. You never mentioned a "form wizard", provided any code, or even a link to a demo page. Help us help you.

Comment: +1...Well, i didnt mentioned such, because it sounded pretty usual problem and there must be a JS solutions for it. I can make a demo but am sure it will look complicated.

Answer (score 2):

can you try with this

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function redirect(URL)
{
   document.location=URL;
   return false;
}
</script>
    <a href="#fragment-1" onclick="return redirect('http://localhost:90/index.php');">Click here</a>
```